# UISegmentedControl refuses to work regardless of implementation

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode-storyboard

I just cannot get UISegmentedControl to work. Not even to do some simple things like change colors. I think I've tried at least a dozen different implementations but here is my latest one.

```
import UIKit

class FirebaseSegmentedView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var firstContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var secondContainer: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func segmentValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        let getIndex = segment.selectedSegmentIndex

        switch (getIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.firstContainer.isHidden = false
            self.secondContainer.isHidden = true
        case 1:
            self.firstContainer.isHidden = true
            self.secondContainer.isHidden = false
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard.

[image]

The ViewContainers do both work. The first one loads and I can see the second one when I scroll the first one out of place. I'm just trying to make a simple segmented control to hide one and show the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem, right in the screen shot you showed of your storyboard:

[image]

See where it says Touch Up Inside? That's the problem. Touch Up Inside is the wrong control event! When you tap a segment of a UISegmentedControl, you don't get a Touch Up Inside event; you get a Value Changed event. Fix it so that your segmented control emits a Value Changed event with `segmentValueChanged` as its action function, and you'll be all set.

Comment: Wow, that worked. I was convinced it was the right event too. Thanks